# Adding Fetch data to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, innerhtml

I am trying to pull 7 products from an API and display them in the DOM. When I try create a div for each product and insert to the HTML I get one div with ',,,,,,,' inside it. It looks like the request is working as I am able to console log the data from the API.

```js
const results = document.getElementById('result');
      
fetch('http://localhost:1337/products')
.then(response => response.json())
.then((data) =>{
results.innerHTML = data.map(product =>{ 
  console.log(product.meal);
    `
  <div class="result">
    <h3>${product.meal}</h3>
    <p>${product.description}</p>
    <p>${product.price}</p>
  </div>
    `
  })
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Med Kitchen Prep</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    

<section id="a">
   
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <a id="logopic" href="/"><img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo image"></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meals</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header-content">
          <h1>
            Mediterranean Kitchen Prep
          </h1>
          <p class="lead">
            Mediterranean Meals Delivered To Your Doorstep
          </p>
          <ul>
          <li><a id="view-meals" href="#">View Our Meals</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
     
</section>

<section id="b">
  <h2>All Meals</h2>
  <div id="result" class="result"></div>
</section>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using `forEach`

```js
const results = document.getElementById('result');
const data = [{
    meal: 'meal-1',
    description: 'desc-1',
    price: 'price-1'
  },
  {
    meal: 'meal-2',
    description: 'desc-2',
    price: 'price-2'
  },
  {
    meal: 'meal-3',
    description: 'desc-3',
    price: 'price-3'
  }
]

data.forEach(product => {
  results.innerHTML += `
  <div class="result">
    <h3>${product.meal}</h3>
    <p>${product.description}</p>
    <p>${product.price}</p>
  </div>
    `
})
```

```html
<section id="b">
  <h2>All Meals</h2>
  <div id="result" class="result"></div>
</section>
```

If you intend to use `map` then instead of accessing dom for appending each element , you can `join` with `,` delimiter and then append dom after iteration is complete

```js
const results = document.getElementById('result');
const data = [{
    meal: 'some meal-1',
    description: 'some desc-1',
    price: 'some price-1'
  },
  {
    meal: 'some meal-2',
    description: 'some desc-2',
    price: 'some price-2'
  },
  {
    meal: 'some meal-3',
    description: 'some desc-3',
    price: 'some price-3'
  }
]

let view = data.map((product) => {
  return `<div class="result">
       <h3>${product.meal}</h3>
       <p>${product.description}</p>
       <p>${product.price}</p>
    </div>`

}).join(',');

results.innerHTML = view;
```

```html
<section id="b">
  <h2>All Meals</h2>
  <div id="result" class="result"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Manjar please check before downvoting. This code will definitely work.

Comment: however the key is not to use the foreach, but to aggregate the value in the innerHTML

Comment: @Manjar no difference from original version.Only data is added now.

Comment: Ok, sorry, in my mind i though you can't assign the HTML directly to the innerHTML, but i have tested, and you can do it

Answer (score -1):

You can use `forEach` and append the innerHTML like so. I am using a mockapi to show the democode.

`map` does not work as you have to iterate again and append the data as string.

```js
const results = document.getElementById('result');

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data.forEach(product => {
      results.innerHTML += `
  <div class="result">
    <h3>${product.title}</h3>
  </div>
    `
    })

  });
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Med Kitchen Prep</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <section id="a">

    <nav id="main-nav">
      <a id="logopic" href="/"><img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo image"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Meals</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="header-content">
      <h1>
        Mediterranean Kitchen Prep
      </h1>
      <p class="lead">
        Mediterranean Meals Delivered To Your Doorstep
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="view-meals" href="#">View Our Meals</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section id="b">
    <h2>All Meals</h2>
    <div id="result" class="result"></div>
  </section>
```

You need to `return` the value inside the `map` function. `map` will return the new array with modified values.

```
const results = document.getElementById('result');

fetch('http://localhost:1337/products')
.then(response => response.json())
.then((data) =>{
results.innerHTML = data.map(product =>{ 
  console.log(product.meal);
    return `
  <div class="result">
    <h3>${product.meal}</h3>
    <p>${product.description}</p>
    <p>${product.price}</p>
  </div>
    `
  })

});
```

Comment: It will not work because you must assign a DomElement node to the innerHTML, you can't assign text

Comment: @Manjar `map` will not work as you have to loop again and add the string to dom. But forEach will work. You can check the above demo.

Comment: you can do it both with map or foreach doesn't really matter, however my previous comment was wrong, you can assign Html directly to innerHTML, however the result of the data.map is an array, so it does require to be aggregated

Comment: I think that is what I said if you read my answer. `map` returns a new array

Answer (score -1):

When using map, you have to return something within the function-
Means you should return the string which you are binding the values into.

```js
results.innerHTML = data.map(product => {
    console.log(product.meal);
    return `
        <div class="result">
            <h3>${product.meal}</h3>
            <p>${product.description}</p>
            <p>${product.price}</p>
        </div>
    `;
})
```